# AES key derivation function

Tags: java, openssl, cryptography, aes

I have a bash script which uses openssl to encrypt data, and Java code which decrypts the result.  Based on my earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343894/aes-encrypt-with-openssl-command-line-tool-and-decrypt-in-java/8352010#8352010), I'm now able to enter a password in openssl, and copy the resulting key/iv into Java.  This relies on using the -nosalt option in openssl.  I'd like to remove that option, and take password/salt/iv from openssl and pass it into a JDK key derivation function.

Here's the openssl script I'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -in test -out test.enc -p
```

When I run this, and enter a password, it prints out the following for example.

```
salt=820E005048F1DF74
key=16023FBEB58DF4EB36229286419F4589
iv=DE46F8904224A0E86E8F8F08F03BCC1A
```

When I try the same password/salt/iv in Java, I'm not able to decrypt test.enc.  I tried Java code based on the answer by @erickson in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256bit-aes-encryption).  Here's the snippet.

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 1024, 128);
SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
```

If I print the "secret" that's generated, it's not the same as the "key" that openssl printed.  Do I need to change one of the Java parameters to match how openssl is deriving its key?

Comment: OpenSSL enc uses either PKCS#5 1.5 or a non-standard key-derivation function depending on the digest (-md arg, or MD5 by default). And 1 iteration. The KDF is EVP_BytesToKey: http://openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html