# openssl not decrypted files encrypted by pycrypto

Tags: python, openssl, aes, pycrypto

i encrypt file in python:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
key = Random.new().read(16)
iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
with open(in_file, 'rb') as fin, open(out_file, 'wb') as fout:
    fout.write(iv)
    while True:
        chunk = fin.read(16*1024)
        if len(chunk) == 0:
             break
        elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
             chunk += b' ' * (16 - len(chunk) % 16)
        fout.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk)
print base64.b32encode(key)
```

but when after what  i try decrypt it with openssl:
`openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in enc -out new.zip`
it returns bag magic number
what i doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to AES encrypt/decrypt files using Python/PyCrypto in an OpenSSL-compatible way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761458/how-to-aes-encrypt-decrypt-files-using-python-pycrypto-in-an-openssl-compatible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Program is using 128 bit AES key for encryption, as seen from the line:

```
key = Random.new().read(16)
```

So, instead of using

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in enc -out new.zip
```

use this

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -d -in enc -out new.zip
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't help. i still getting `bad magic number`.

Comment: you have to provide the key used and iv in command line too. Kinldy check this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343894/aes-encrypt-with-openssl-command-line-tool-and-decrypt-in-java